# Compilation failures with C++ ranges

Tags: c++, std-ranges

Here is range example that somehow doesn't build with clang17/gcc13:

- transform from vector builds *view* on internal  vectors. That should be fine, ownership holds by the `input` variable
- join builds a view on returned sequence on `views` - should be fine as well
- `subrange` however failed to compile, states that iterators are not comparable.

Its blow up my mind - why???

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> input = {{0, 1, 2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}};
    auto range = input | std::views::transform([](auto &i) {return i | std::views::all;}) | std::views::join;

    for (auto i : range) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    // Till here everything was fine but now fun begins:
    auto l = range.begin(), r = range.begin();
    std::advance(r, 2);

    // Has to force subrange types by <decltype> otherwise compiler just report deducing error:
    // that subsrange looks quite legal but doesn't compile
    auto subrange = std::ranges::subrange<decltype(l)>(std::move(l), std::move(r));
    for (auto i : subrange) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

Clang states that:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:223:49: error: no type named 'difference_type' in 'std::iterator_traits<std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>, (lambda at <source>:8:48)>>::_Iterator<false>>'
  223 |       typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type __d = __n;
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::advance<std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>, (lambda at <source>:8:48)>>::_Iterator<false>, int>' requested here
   15 |     std::advance(r, 2);
      |          ^
<source>:18:34: error: constraints not satisfied for class template 'subrange' [with _It = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>, (lambda at <source>:8:48)>>::_Iterator<false>, _Sent = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>, (lambda at <source>:8:48)>>::_Iterator<false>, _Kind = std::ranges::subrange_kind::unsized]
   18 |     auto subrange = std::ranges::subrange<decltype(l)>(std::move(l), std::move(r));
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_util.h:252:42: note: because 'sentinel_for<std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >, (lambda at <source>:8:48)> >::_Iterator<false>, std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >, (lambda at <source>:8:48)> >::_Iterator<false> >' evaluated to false
  252 |   template<input_or_output_iterator _It, sentinel_for<_It> _Sent = _It,
      |                                          ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:641:10: note: because '__detail::__weakly_eq_cmp_with<std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >, (lambda at <source>:8:48)> >::_Iterator<false>, std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >, (lambda at <source>:8:48)> >::_Iterator<false> >' evaluated to false
  641 |       && __detail::__weakly_eq_cmp_with<_Sent, _Iter>;
      |          ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/concepts:296:10: note: because '__t == __u' would be invalid: invalid operands to binary expression ('const remove_reference_t<_Iterator<false>>' (aka 'const std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>, (lambda at <source>:8:48)>>::_Iterator<false>') and 'const remove_reference_t<_Iterator<false>>' (aka 'const std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>, (lambda at <source>:8:48)>>::_Iterator<false>'))
**  296 |           { __t == __u } -> __boolean_testable;
**      |                 ^
```

subrange of `join` on a range of views doesn't compile with cryptical error about iterators are not comparable. I would expect that code compiles/works and don't understand what is wrong with it

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view/begin <- I think the Notes section may apply to your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, since the inner range is a prvalue, the resulted `range` will only model `input_range`, which means its iterator only models `input_iterator`.

In C++20, `input_iterator`'s post-increment operator can return `void`, in which case it is not sufficient to be a valid C++17 iterator, so you cannot use the `std::advance` applied to C++17 iterators on it. Instead, you should use `ranges::advance`.

In addition, since `input_iterator` is not guaranteed to be comparable to itself (as in your example), that is to say, it cannot serve as its sentinel, this is why `ranges::subrange` cannot be constructed, i.e. `decltype(l)` does not satisfy `sentinel_for<decltype(l)>`.